# Redux using combineReducers returning blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I am importing `reducers` with their defined name my application working fine but when I am using `combineReducers` its returning blank page.

`store.js` code is:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from '../reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
var routes =(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <Route path="/testingtask" component={TestingTask}>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

`TestingTask.js` is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TaskContainer from '../containers/TaskContainer';



export default class TestingTask extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <TaskContainer />
        );
    }
}
module.exports = TestingTask;
```

`TaskContainer.js` is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {  Link } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { fetchPostsWithRedux,fetchPosts,fetchPostsError,fetchPostsSuccess,fetchPostsRequest } from '../actions/TaskAction';

class TaskContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchPostsWithRedux()
  }
    render(){
      return (
            <ul>
                {
            this.props.posts && 
          this.props.posts.map((post,i) =>{
            return(
                <li key={i}>{JSON.parse(post.form_data).title}</li>
            )
          })
        }
        </ul>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
    posts: state.posts
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
     return bindActionCreators({fetchPostsWithRedux: fetchPostsWithRedux}, dispatch)

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TaskContainer);
```

`TaskAction.js` is:

```
export function fetchPostsRequest(){
  return {
    type: "FETCH_REQUEST"
  }
}

export function fetchPostsSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
    payload
  }
}

export function fetchPostsError() {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_ERROR"
  }
}

export function fetchPostsWithRedux() {
    return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchPostsRequest());
    return fetchPosts().then(([response, json]) =>{
        if(response.status === 200){
        dispatch(fetchPostsSuccess(json.data))
      }
      else{
        dispatch(fetchPostsError())
      }
    })
  }
}

export function fetchPosts() {
  const URL = "api-url";
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  return fetch(URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            api_token: user.api_token,
            type: 'task',
          })
        }).then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}
```

`TaskReducer.js` is:

```
import {
  FETCH_REQUEST,
  FETCH_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_ERROR
} from '../actions/TaskAction';

export default function TaskReducer (state = {}, action)  {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_REQUEST":
      return state;
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS": 
      return {...state, posts: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`/reducers/index.js` is:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import TaskReducer from './TaskReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  TaskReducer,
})
```

Please note when using `import reducer from '../reducers/TaskReducer';` in `store.js` its working fine.

Comment: What do yu mean by `import reducer from '../reducers/index'; in store.js its working fine.`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Sorry it was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Have you exported login and register reducers too

Comment: Yes. But when I am using just `TaskReducer` its not working too.

Comment: Can you try and createStore with Login and Register reducers also and see if it stillworkds. Also it should not help but can you just try `import reducer from '../reducers';` You may also see erros in your webpack build log , can you check there also

Comment: I have removed Login and Register for now. Only using TaskReducer in combineReducers. Still blank page. There are no errors in webpack build.

Comment: Try console.log(reducer) in store.js

Comment: Its returning a function `function combination() {
     var state = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? {} : arguments[0];
     var action = arguments[1];
 
     if (sanityError) {
       throw sanityError;
     }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `combineReducers` function split the state in objects that you can access through the name of the reducer.

Therefore, this function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
    posts: state.posts
  }
}
```

has to become

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
    posts: state.TaskReducer.posts
  }
}
```

Take a look to the [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) and to the example:

> **Returns**
>
> (Function): A reducer that invokes every reducer inside the reducers
>   object, and constructs a state object with the same shape.

If you want to define a different name for the store key, just change the object you pass to the function:

```
export default combineReducers({
  task: TaskReducer,
})

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
    posts: state.task.posts
  }
}
```